# Nikon SD Memory Cards, are they good?

Tags: nikon, memory-card, sdhc

I've bought a Nikon D7000 Kit (Nikon D7000 Kit AF-S DX 18-105 mm VR) that includes two Nikon branded SD Memory Cards. I've tried them and till now I have no complaints, but due to the lack of some well known high performance SD Cards, I can not compare them.

Does anybody know how good those cards are and/or if it is recommendable to buy i.e. two SanDisk Extreme III SDHC Class 10 cards?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4 GB Nikon SD (received with a D5000):

- read: ~7 MB/s
- write: ~3 MB/s

16 GB SanDisk Ultra 100x SDHC:

- read: ~20 MB/s
- write: ~12 MB/s

2 GB Kingston microSD:

- read: ~18 MB/s
- write: ~10 MB/s

Both were tested on a Transcend P8 card reader, in "optimize for performance" mode.

Answer (score 4):

Rob Galbraith has put together an enormous database of CF and SD performance metrics in various cameras.  It starts [here](http://www.robgalbraith.com/bins/multi_page.asp?cid=6007) with an extremely thorough explanation of how the cards work, and then a database organized by camera.  I'm pretty sure you'll be able to see how your cards stack up to the others there.

He doesn't have the D7000 up yet, but I'd suspect that a camera like the d90, which is also SD, would have similar performance.

Comment: Thanks for the link.
Unfortunately the Nikon SD Memory Cards are not listed in his - huge - database. At least I know now that it's gonna be a Sandisk, if I buy one (two). However I figured out, that the Nikon SD Memory Cards are Class 4 (4 MB/s) which will be definitively slower than the top notch card listed in Rob's DB for the D90.